# Assigning a weighted random variable to a new column in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, random, dplyr

I have a Dataframe that looks like this in R:

**df1**

| date | location | daytype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-9-1 | NT | Thur |
| 2022-9-2 | NT | Fri |
| 2022-9-3 | AP | Sat |
| 2022-9-4 | AP | Sun |
| 2022-9-5 | NT | Mon |

I want to create a new column for either a morning or an afternoon shift based on random weight sampling:

**df2**

| shift | weight |
| --- | --- |
| Morning | 0.8 |
| Evening | 0.2 |

Is there a way to do this?

`df1$shift <- sample(df2, prob = df$weight)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to specify the `size` as the number of rows of 'df1' and `replace = TRUE`

```
df1$shift <-  with(df2, sample(shift, prob = weight, 
    size = nrow(df1), replace = TRUE))
```